# PHP session_start() causing HTTP requests to hang

Tags: php, session

I have an application I've written in PHP from scratch. I'm using PHP's native session handler functions for handling user authentication and persistence.

When testing on the development server, everything is peachy. Authentication, persistence, etc, works fine.

When installed on the production server, everything works fine up until the user authentication -- when the app actually writes data to the session object, suddenly the HTTP request that follows it completely hangs exactly when session_start() is executed.

I suspected the temporary session files were being locked by PHP and never released, so I tried following up the spots where the app is writing to the session object with `session_write_close()`, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Does this sound like a file lock issue or is this something else? I'm confused on why session_write_close doesn't seem to be taking care of the file lock issue if that's the case, which is why I'm wondering if there could be something else at play here.

Any possible thoughts or ideas?

Reply to Pekka's great suggestions:

- The production server is a linux environment. phpinfo reports `Linux wynn 2.6.18-164.9.1.el5PAE #1 SMP`
- The page is not calling itself
- I can read/write the session folder and files. I can see the authentication data that gets serialized into the files from the auth attempt.

Comment: This sounds like a configuration issue. Make sure that PHP is reporting all errors, i.e., `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and either display or log all errors. (You might even want to enable `display_startup_errors` in your php.ini) - reporting all errors may shed light on what's going on.

Comment: Yes, great idea - this is going to be my next step -- unfortunately my 'production' environment is a shared host that I have very little control over, but I'll be contacting the technical support to see if they can help me out with this.

Comment: @andy Did you accept my answer to clean up your list, or did something actually do the trick? Would be interested to know.

Comment: @andy just saw your comment, cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a few ideas - in addition to pygorex's comment to first turn up the error_reporting, which should definitely come first.

- Probably not it, but there are three hangups described in the User Contributed Notes to session_start:

  - [**When using /dev/random as session entropy file**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#78394)
  - [**When page is calling itself with the same session**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#69630)
  - [**On Windows**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#71666)
- Can you read your session cookie and check whether a session file of that name exists in your /tmp directory? Is that file writable? Does it contain data?
- If all else fails, the [**manual page on session_save_handler()**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) has what seems like a full custom replacement for the default session handling functions. Consider using those for detailed debugging.

Comment: Marking this as correct - turns out it wasn't a session problem afterall, but these solutions gave me enough places to debug that I could entirely rule-out a session issue. Thank you.

Comment: Not calling `session_write_close()` in a long-running server-side handler is what caused it for me.

Comment: @mattnedrich  - Those who are not able to access above URLs. Just remove **"de3."** from the beginning of the URL.